# NullPointerException in a Service class for Firebase

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have a Flutter based Android app. Google Play Console shows some crashes due to the following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myapp.app.service.FirebaseService$1.run (FirebaseService.java:7)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

`FirebaseService.java` (see below for the FirebaseService class code) is part of my code & it's pretty basic service class. This class is there just to receive push notifications in the background. Also, this error seems to be happening for small number of devices.

The FirebaseService class code is below. And yes, I have the FirebaseService correctly listed in AndroidMenifest.xml as this code works on most of the devices.

As you can see the FirebaseService.java:7 (line 7) as per the exception, it points to some import, so I am not sure what exactly is wrong or how to go about fixing it.

Any idea what could be causing this error?

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.myapp.app.MainActivity;
import com.myapp.app.service.job.SyncDataWorker;
import com.myapp.app.util.DeviceUtils;
import com.myapp.app.util.GeneralUtils;
import com.myapp.app.util.LocalNotificationUtil;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;
    
    public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String TAG = FirebaseService.class.getName();
    
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived");
    
            
            // Check if message contains a data payload.
            if (null != remoteMessage.getData() && !remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty()) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
                if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(remoteMessage.getData().get("type"))) {
                    handleFbMessageResponse(remoteMessage.getData());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only obvious thing that could be `null` is `remoteMessage`, are you sure it isn't?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont have a null check for remoteMessage, but since the exception call-stack wasn't pointing to onMessageReceived function, I thought the error is happening somewhere else. But, I'll add a null check for remoteMessage and see if it helps.

Comment: Which line exactly is it pointing to?

Comment: As you can in the exception stack trace in my orignal message, it says line 7 `at com.myapp.app.service.FirebaseService$1.run (FirebaseService.java:7)` which is some import statement...